# microsoft sharepoint accessing documents using REST API return 404

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I have created a site in ms sharepoint and in the documents created a word doc. I want to access all the documents in the 'Documents' location using REST API.

I created the application to generate app id and secret using: 
https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/application

Then i generated an access token using: 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2FSites.ReadWrite.All&state=12345

The scope I used is 
**Sites.ReadWrite.All**  based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/permissions_reference?view=odsp-graph-online

After i got the access token I am making a REST call as follows:

```
https://4development106.sharepoint.com/<mysite name>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents')

accept: application/json;odata=verbose
Authorization: "Bearer" + "my access token"
```

But i get a 404.

I do have a document created in the site under documents. Please advise

Comment: try it as `https://4development106.sharepoint.com/<mysite name>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/<mysite name>/Shared Documents') and check
`

Comment: thanks no luck though :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I access a Sharepoint site to get the known list. I think you'll need the same initial url structure:

```
https://my.sharepoint.com/sites/oh/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('#{list_title}')
```

i.e. there's an intial `sites` path segment before the site name, in this case the name of the site is `oh`

so you could try:

```
https://4development106.sharepoint.com/sites/<mysite name>/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Shared Documents')
```

Comment: yes i think that was definitely issue as now i am seeing a access denied error which is a good sign.

Comment: some parts of Sharepoint require Application Permissions (commandline app) rather than Delegated Permissions (user involved). The former requires an X509 uploaded to azure and a signed JWT rather than access_token

Comment: Thanks for chiming in again. You seems very experienced and i am with one day experience with all this. So, my requirement is to write a html/js (more specifically an angular web app) In the app I want to see a list of the documents under 'Shared Folders'.  and basically let user access those. what kind of setup i need to do to make those REST calls?